# Automatic creation of snapshots using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snapshot

I have completed the automatic creation of snapshots using the following link :

https://blog.powerupcloud.com/2016/02/15/automate-ebs-snapshots-using-lambda-function/

As written in the code, filtering is done based on ***tags*** of VMs. Instead of creating a VM with a Backup or backup tag, I want to create snapshots of all except for some names.

I do not want to add extra tags to VMs. Instead, I want to write an if condition in my filters. I would provide the names of my Test VMs and if the VM tag matches that, snapshot would not be created. If it does not match, snapshots have to be created. Can I do that?

Ex : I have four VMs in my account.

```
VM 1 --> Prod1,
VM 2 --> Prod2,
VM 3 --> Prod3, 
VM 4 --> Test1.
```

Acc to example, I need to be able to write an if condition which includes my test VM tag 'Test1'. If the tag matches this, the snapshot should not be created. If it does not match, snapshots have to be created.

So, for doing this, how should I change my code?

Comment: You will need a simple way of identifying which machines you wish to snapshot. How do you want your code to work? Do you want it to snapshot *everything except those with a particular tag*? What should happen if there is a 5th instance?

Comment: Exactly. I want it to snapshot everything except those with a particular tags. I have two instances in my account whose snapshots need not be created. For rest of the instances[running or stopped], I want the snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a tag for all your three servers with key 'Backup'. The script is filtering the instances on the key names only.

Comment: That's not what I want. I do not want to add extra tags to VMs. Instead, I want to write an if condition in my filters. I would provide the names of my Test VMs and if the VM tag matches that, snapshot would not be created. If it does not match, snapshots have to be created. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code that picks up which VMs need to be backed up is this:

```
reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['Backup', 'True']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )
```

As you can see, it uses boto's [describe_instances](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) and a filter limits the number of instances that will be processed. If you would like to backup everything except for those which are non-prod in your environment, you should consider tagging your non-prod instances with something like Backup=NO.

Comment: That's not what I want. I do not want to add extra tags to VMs. Instead, I want to write an if condition in my filters. I would provide the names of my Test VMs and if the VM tag matches that, snapshot would not be created. If it does not match, snapshots have to be created. Can I do that?

Comment: Each instance name is also a tag by default, like Name=yourhostname, so all you need to do is pass multiple values `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=instance1, instance2, instance3"`. This the VMs you want. It works in AWS cli, it will work here too, please look up the documentation and try it.

Comment: Yaa..that is ok. But, 2 to 3 new instances get launched in my account almost every 3 days. So, i can't keep editing my code every alternate day

Answer (score 0):

To backup all servers *except* those marked with a tag:

- Get a list of **all** servers
- Get a list of servers **with the 'do not backup' flag** and remove them from the first list
- Do the backup

It will require two calls to `describe_instances()`.